# How to fill hidden field with Capybara?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I've already found that when I want to set value to text field, text area or password field, I can use id, name or label as `something` in `fill_in something, :with => some_value`.  However such approach fails when I try to set value to `<input type="hidden">` field (and I want to do it because those are normally filled client-side scripts which I test separately).  How could I set such a hidden field with Capybara?  Is it possible?

HTML:

```
<input id='offer_latitude' name='offer[latitude]' type='hidden'>
<input id='offer_longitude' name='offer[longitude]' type='hidden'>
```

spec:

```
describe "posting new offer" do
  it "should add new offer" do
    visit '/offer/new'
    fill_in 'offer[latitude]', :with => '11.11'
    fill_in 'offer[longitude]', :with => '12.12'
    click_on 'add'
  end
end
```

gives:

```
1) posting new offer should add new offer
   Failure/Error: fill_in 'offer[latitude]', :with => '11.11'
   Capybara::ElementNotFound:
     cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'offer[latitude]' found
```

Comment: normally a person can't fill in a hidden field, so therefor capybara doesn't fill them in.  see  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ruby-capybara/EstLVItkyrA  for more discussion.  But normally you either populate it on the server or use javascript..

Comment: @Doon's comment is very true. If you want to inspect/alter hidden input, most probably you're using wrong tool. Capybara is designed to test whole application in various scenarios, not to test your JS components. Checkout [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) or [Chai](http://chaijs.com/).  However there are situations where it's sensible, for example filling HTML5 inputs which are polyfilled in incompatible browsers.  Polyfills often hide proper input and insert additional markup.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to locate the hidden field and set its value. There are a couple ways, this is probably the simplest

```
find(:xpath, "//input[@id='my_hidden_field_id']").set "my value"
```

If you're executing a client_side script in production, you could just tell capybara to run it with a javascript-compliant driver

```
page.execute_script("$('hidden_field_id').my_function()")
```

Comment: Yes, XPath did the job.  You have a typo near @, it should rather be `find(:xpath, "//input[@id='my_hidden_field_id']").set "my value"`

Comment: CSS matchers worked fine for me as well `find("#my_hidden_field").set("my value")`

Comment: FWIW, this no longer works for me as of Capybara 2.7.1. Fixed by passing `visible: false` to the `#find` method.

Comment: @RyanDlugosz - `page.execute_script` definitely still works, even with Capybara's new constraints on clicking hidden/invisible DOM elements.

Comment: Works Perfect with skalee and ryan-dlugosz comments combined:
`find("#my_hidden_field", visible: false).set("my value")`

Answer (score 60):

There are many ways to achieve the same result. The one I like the most is:

```
first('input#id.class', visible: false).set("your value")
```

Comment: first('input#id.class', visible: false).set('your value')

Comment: Works thanks! It feel easier to read than the xpath solution.

Comment: Considering that the id is unique you can go with ```find('#id').set("value")```

Comment: `visible: false` found it, but I am getting this error on `set()` .. `Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)`

Comment: page.execute_script("document.getElementById('some_id').value = #{some_value}")

Answer (score 7):

If you're using poltergeist/phantomjs as a driver and jquery isn't working for ya, there's always good old fashioned js:

```
page.execute_script("document.getElementById('#some-id').value = 'some-value'");
```

Comment: Use `evaluate_script` only when you're interested in returned value (and it's not an object). `execute_script` is better in this situation.

Comment: Nice answer, but jQuery is working with poltergeist/phantomjs.

Comment: Probably your id is 'some-id', not '#some-id'.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me

```
find_field(id: 'your_hidden_field_id', type: :hidden).set('Field value here')
```