# Using Capybara how would I would I overwrite an existing field value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am currently testing a form on a page with Capybara that has existing values filled out in the form's fields. I want to test being able to put new values into the fields and submitting the form with the new values.

When I try using Capybara's fill_in method it ignores the fields that have existing values. Is there anyway to overwrite fields with existing values in Capybara?

I'll include the form below:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/submissions/1/reviews/4" class=
  "simple_form edit_review" id="edit_review_4" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"
  name="edit_review_4">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
      <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#10003;"><input name="_method" type=
      "hidden" value="put"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value=
      "gJ/KKAodeIJD8PPnRNeN4GaGb/yqvUDHrsnl9LqLP/c=">
    </div>

    <div class="input integer optional">
      <label class="integer optional control-label" for=
      "review_rating">Rating</label><input class="numeric integer optional" id=
      "review_rating" name="review[rating]" step="1" type="number" value="33">
    </div>

    <div class="input text required">
      <label class="text required control-label" for="review_comment"><abbr title=
      "required">*</abbr> Comment</label>
      <textarea class="text required" cols="40" id="review_comment" name=
      "review[comment]" rows="20">
hellofsdf
</textarea>
    </div><input class="btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update Review">
  </form>
```

The Capybara code I've tried is:

```
find(:xpath, "//*[(@id = 'review_comment')]").set "hello"
```

I've also tried a similar approach with the rating field since the rating is a text field and the comment is a text area, but I still can't get it to change.

Comment: Post resulting HTML, please

Comment: Updated as per your request

Comment: Strange... The following code works for me - https://gist.github.com/4696481

Comment: It is strange, that code works for me too so it must be something with my app. My app is located (test problem highlighted) here if you want to see if you can find the cuprit: https://github.com/jklina/fixelpuckers/blob/reviews/spec/features/reviews_spec.rb#L88

Answer (score 1):

using find with XSLT expression should do the trick

```
find(:xpath, "//input[@id='field_with_default_value_id']").set "my value"
```

Comment: can you post a sample of the form?

Comment: This answer does nearly the same as OP did and doesn't solve problem

Comment: he didn't post the code or the xpath before, the question was a simple paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript driver like phantomjs/poltergeist and then use javascript to set values like that.

```
page.evaluate_script("document.getElementById('#some-id').value = 'some-value'");
```

Similar to my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804897/how-to-fill-hidden-field-with-capybara/21893022) question.