# How to do functional-testing bootstrap-star-rating in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, functional-testing

I'm trying to do functional-testing in rails with cucumber and capybara, to test bootstrap-star-rating, but i don't know how do that. 
I'd like to describe this step **'When I select 1 star to rate'**

In view

```
<%= form_tag("/medics/rating", method: "post") do %> 
                    <input id="input-2a" class="rating" name="grade" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="1" data-stars=5 
                        data-glyphicon="false">
                     <%= hidden_field_tag :medic_id, @medic.id %>
                    <%= submit_tag 'Avaliar' , class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success' %>
                <%end%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, how i write this test?

```
When(/^I select 1 star to rate$/) do

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had the same problem and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639865/using-capybara-how-would-i-would-i-overwrite-an-existing-field-value). In short, use a JavaScript driver such as poltergeist/selenium (I'm using Selenium) and provide the value to the input using page.evaluate_script.

I'm not using Cucumber, however, here's what worked for me with minitest and capybara/minitest/rails:

```
script = "document.getElementById('review_rating').value = '3'"

click_link 'add a review'
fill_in 'review[take_away]', with: 'Review takeaway'
fill_in 'review[body]', with: 'Review body'
page.evaluate_script(script)

click_button 'Review!'
```

Since this is 100% Capybara syntax, the fact that I'm using minitest and you're using Cucumber shouldn't make any difference.