# Is it possible to interact with hidden elements with capybara?

Tags: capybara, attachment

I have a file field that has `opacity: 0` and is overlaping a fake button. Its a common css technic to fake a sort of "Upload button" that displays consistently across different browsers.

Capybara doesn't allows me to call `attach_file` on that input. The error is `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`.

Anybody knows any way to force capybara to interact with invisible elements?

The answer is still unanswered, but I've found a work around. Nothing intelligent, just make visible the element with a simple script

```
  page.execute_script %Q{
    $('#photos').css({opacity: 1, transform: 'none'});
  }
```

I post it for the record.

Comment: It may be hard to do it. Try to start from JS [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Does_WebDriver_support_file_uploads?). But it may not work in all cases and browsers

Comment: Looks like you are not using capybara-webkit (because of "Selenium::WebDriver::Error" in error message) so I removed capybara-webkit tag from your question

Comment: It may already be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10805128/914986

Comment: The work around works fine! Thanks

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can interact with hidden elements using the `visible: false` property in Capybara.

If you want to click on hidden element use:

```
find("#photos", visible: false).click
```

Don't use `click_button('#photo')` directly

Comment: @mc. On which element you'r clicking, paste the structure here

Comment: This may only work because the element has opacity: 0 not visibility: hidden (or similar). You can not click on hidden elements directly

Comment: The answer from @Thomas Walpole (here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44443849/2809881) is a much more useful and direct answer to the problem of attaching a file to an invisible file input.

Comment: Also note that `find("#photos", visible: false)` will match **visible** #photos, too. If you want to match invisible elements only, you need `find("#photos", visible: :hidden)` as described by Thomas Walpole here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361214/capybara-with-rails-how-to-find-only-invisible-elements/53363238#53363238

Answer (score 19):

[The author of Capybara recommends setting `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/761#issuecomment-7156472) immediately prior to needing to see the invisible element, and resetting it afterwards:

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
click_button 'my invisible button'
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true
```

Comment: When you read it, he only recommends this as a workaround to a particular issue. In general, it's not a good solution because particular tests shouldn't alter a global option like that. See http://makandracards.com/makandra/7617-change-how-capybara-sees-or-ignores-hidden-elements

Answer (score 8):

In general interacting with non-visible elements should not be possible when using Capybara (you can find them using the `visible: false/hidden` option in most finders but not actually do anything to them).  However, the file input is a special case because of how common it is to hide the element and, due to security restrictions, no other way to actually add a file by interacting with the pages visible elements.  Because of this `attach_file` has a `make_visible` option which can be used to have Capybara make the element visible, attach the file, and then reset the CSS to the original setting.

```
attach_file('photos', file_path, make_visible: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Miquel, thanks for workaraund.

I have similar issue for interacting with hidden file input on C# binding for Selenium Webdriver 2.35 and Firefox 24. To make file selection working did similar trick:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webdriver).ExecuteScript("$('#fileUploadInput').css({opacity: 1, transform: 'none'});");

IWebElement e = webdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#fileUploadInput")));

e.SendKeys("c:\\temp\\inputfile.txt");
```

Comment: Oh. Alexander, are you the same guy from the Open Watcom usenet/newsgroup?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving it a different route.

`execute_script()` was giving me a hard time (it would freeze test execution on FireFox), so this is what I did:

I already had an appropriate javascript file. I appended the following

```
<% if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "test" %>
  $('#photos').show()
<% end %>
```

I also had to append `.erb` to my javascript file for proper Rails asset handling.

And in my test file, I was already setting `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"`

This way I could just dumb down the UI for test, and yet maintain the look and feel for production.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way with elements that has the CSS style `display:none;` set:

```
page.execute_script("$('.all-hidden-elements').show();");
all('.all-hidden-elements').first.click
```

Answer (score 0):

If the hidden element is nested in a visible parent element (e.g. a hidden input inside a visible label), you can click on the parent instead. If you still want to find the input by ID, you can traverse to the parent like so:

```
find('#hidden_input').find(:xpath, '..').click
```