# Capybara with Rails: how to find ONLY invisible elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, capybara

I am using Capybara(capybara 3.1.0) for system tests in Rails project(Rails 5.2.0).

What is the way to ensure element is not visible.

I was using the `visible: false` option until I just found it matches visible elements, too.

For example I use:

```
find("h1", visible: false).text
```

There is no exception, and the text of the h1 is printed in the console, while h1 is definitely visible.

Is this expected? What is the logic behind this behavior? And what is the correct way to ensure element is not visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Capybara was first released, the value of visible (true or false) meant to enable or disable the visibility filter, for legacy test reasons that has stayed.  You can also specify values of :visible, :hidden, :all (https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method) where `:visible` behaves the same as `true`, `:all` behaves the same as `false` and `:hidden` will return only non-visible elements.

This means your `find` would need to become

```
find("h1", visible: :hidden).text(:all)
```

With the `:all` parameter needed if you want the text because `text` defaults to only visible text (https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#text-instance_method)