# filling hidden fields with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara

I am proceeding to integration testing and I have to populate some hidden field. The problem is this seem not to be taken into account

```
it "submits project form" do
    page.all("#project_description", :visible => false).set(@project.description)
    click_button  "submit"
    expect(page).to have_content @project.description
end
```

the problem is that I get this error message when launching the task `Description can't be blank`. I am sure the the `hidden field` is found, but the filling is not done. How can I fix it ? (I set `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements` to `false`)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804897/how-to-fill-hidden-field-with-capybara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be the best solution, but you could do it with javascript. For exemple, if you're using jQuery:

```
page.execute_script "$('#project_description').val('#{@project.description}')"
```

If there are some `'` characters  in the `@project.description`, you need to escape them (see [JavaScriptHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html), not sure how to use it in integration test).